Car racing cartoon series where cars race when the portals open and they have to complete the race with in the time limit
I saw a cartoon episode probably in late 90s or early 2000s which was about racing cars and it was probably animated.
What I remember is that group of racers waited for the portals to open and then they race with an other group of racers and they have to finish the race before the portals close. They have a small flying robot with them for repair but that robot is actually a spy for other robots which make their own faction to race in portals. The leader of human group has special vehicle and then because of the spy robot, the robot faction would make cars like that.

This is Hot Wheels: World Race, the defacto prequel to the first of the AcceleRacers series.
From the synopsis:

After attaining his drivers licence on his 16th birthday, naive-teenager Vert Wheeler discovers the Deora II Hot Wheels car. The door on the front of the car opens, and a monitor shows a recording of a mysterious man named Dr. Peter Tezla, inviting him to a competition called the World Race: a contest between seasoned professionals and talented drivers. Driving to a secret location in the Californian desert, the drivers are informed of the race along an interdimensional racetrack called "Highway 35″, created by extraterrestrial beings called Accelerons.
[...]
Meanwhile, as Kurt scarpers from the race, he is found by his
  employers CLYP, led by a mysterious woman named Gelorum.
As the drivers are about to start the fourth leg of the race, Kurt,
  with several CLYP racers, make a break for the portal, enticing the
  other racers to follow. Throughout the ice leg, the CLYP racers try
  and sabotage the race by blocking the track and dropping mines. When
  Markie, who was leading detonates a mine which sees himself
  unconscious naging over a cliff, Kurt betrays the CLYP drivers,
  revealed to be drones, to help Markie.

